# ValueError: shapes (5,14) and (16,) not aligned: 14 (dim 1)!= 16 (dim 0)

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on housing dataset and when trying to fit the linear regression model getting error as mentioned. Complete code as below.
I am not sure where is code going wrong. I tried pasting the code as it is from the reference book.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(housing_prepared, housing_labels)


some_data = housing.iloc[:5]
some_labels = housing_labels.iloc[:5]
some_data_prepared = full_pipeline.transform(some_data)
print("Predictions:\t", lin_reg.predict(some_data_prepared))
```

> ERROR: ValueError: shapes (5,14) and (16,) not aligned: 14 (dim 1) != 16 (dim 0)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: this will very much depend on the dataset, my guess is that you are training and testing on different number of columns. Please include a sample dataset for a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

Hi, I guess you are reading and following the *Hands on Machine Learning with Scikit Learn and Tensorflow* book. The problem also occurred to me.

In the following part of the code you select from the data set the first 5 instances. One of the attributes in the data set which is called *ocean_proximity* is an object and for the linear regression model to be able to operate with it, it must be translated to an integer, which in the book is done with a one hot encoding.

One hot encoding works by analyzing all the categories that can be assigned to the attribute, in this case 5 ('<1H OCEAN', 'INLAND', 'NEAR OCEAN', 'NEAR BAY', 'ISLAND'), and then creating a matrix of that length for each instance and zeroing every element of the matrix except the category of that instance which is assigned a 1 (or another value). For example:

If ocean_proximity equals '<1H OCEAN' the conversion would be [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

In this piece of code you select the five first instances of the data set, but this does not assure you that all the categories in "ocean_proximity" will appear. It could happen that only 3 of them appear or just 1. Therefor if you apply a one hot encoding to those five selected rows and only 3 categories appear (for example just 'INLAND', 'ISLAND' and 'NEAR BAY'), the matrices created by the one hot encoding will be of length 3.

```
some_data = housing.iloc[:5]
some_labels = housing_labels.iloc[:5]
some_data_prepared = full_pipeline.transform(some_data)
```

The error is just telling you that, since the one hot conversion of *some_data* created matrices of a length inferior to 5, the total columns in *some_data_prepared* is 14, which is less than the columns in *housing_prepared* (16), thus making the model unable to predict the prices.

If you transform both *some_data_prepared* and *housing_prepared* into dataframes and then call `.head()` you will see the problem.

[some_data_prepared.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DXLO.png)

[housing_prepared.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dojmN.png)

**Solution**

To solve the problem you must create the columns missing in `some_data_prepared` by creating a zeroed numpy array of shape [5,x] (being 5 the number of rows and x the number of columns missing) and concatenating it to `some_data_prepared` to match the shape of the `housing_prepared` data set.

```
some_data = housing.iloc[:5]

some_labels = housing_labels.iloc[:5]
some_data_prepared = full_pipeline.fit_transform(some_data)

dummy_array = np.zeros((5,1))
some_data_prepared = np.c_[some_data_prepared, dummy_array]

predictions = linear_regression.predict(some_data_prepared)
print("Predictions: ", predictions)
print("Labels: ", some_labels.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing category values (ocean proximity in this case) in `some_data` compared to `housing_prepared` is the issue.

`housing_prepared.shape` gives (16512, 16), but `some_data_prepared.shape` gives (5,14), so add zeros for the missing columns:

```
dummy_array = np.zeros((5,2))
some_data_prepared = np.c_[some_data_prepared,dummy_array]
```

the 2 in `np.zeros` determines the difference of columns

Answer (score 0):

I've at first encountered the same issue on the considered piece of code. After exploring the issues of the *handson-ml* repository, I think I have understood the subtlety which is causing the error here.

My guess is that (as in my case), closing the notebook might have caused what was in memory (and the trained model in particular) to be lost. In my case, I could get the result and avoid the error rerunning the notebook from the beginning.

Instead, from a theoretical viewpoint, you should never call `fit()` or `fit_transform()` on data which is not training data (eg on `some_data`). Here, running `fit_transform(some_data)` and then stacking the dummy array to `some_data_prepared` works, but it forces the model to be trained again on `some_data` rather than on `housing_prepared`, which is not what you want.